# The data is passed from one threadgroup to another and never ends when data is not available due to failures

Tags: jmeter

I am extracting data from http response in one thread group and using that as a request parameter in another thread group. Suppose i have setup 50 users and 10 loops for both the thread groups and there is not enough data for the next thread group due to some failures in the first one, then the thread group keeps waiting for data and never ends. Is this normal?
I tried to setup less number of users and loops for the next thread group so that the loop ends. But, i feel all the data extracted from the first thread group is not utilized. Is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Passing data between thread groups is "not normal" in any way, most probably your test is badly designed.

Also we're not telepathic enough to guess how exactly you're "passing" this data, given 50 users and loops in first thread group my expectation is that in ideal case it would be 500 "parameters" (whatever it is).

If there are failures - the number of these "parameters" will be less so you will need to adjust the number of threads/iterations in the 2nd Thread Group accordingly. Like if there are 10 failures in 1st thread group you will end up with 490 "parameters" only so you will need to use i.e. 70 users and 7 loops in the 2nd thread groups.

So if you're using i.e. [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/#Inter-Thread-Communication) - there is __fifoSize() function which returns the current number of items in the queue, if it's less than 500 - something went wrong in the first thread group.

More "safe" option would be writing the "parameters" into a CSV file in 1st thread group using i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) and reading the file using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) in 2nd thread group